# Few views in an upvote question

Tags: discussion, specific-question, voting

I'm new  in stackexchange and usually my questions have no answer at all, and few viewers, I can't understand why.
For example: [my question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2571827/choose-a-prior-in-a-bayesian-poisson-hierarchical-regression)

I think here I wrote the question in a good way (in fact I get 2 vote) but only 25 viewers saw my question. If my question is written well why in 25 viewers only 2 upvoted?
I think that you have to encourage the users to upvote the question if it's written well

Comment: While statistics questions are welcome here, there is a dedicated statistics Stack Exchange: https://stats.stackexchange.com/ .  You may get answers if you ask a moderator to migrate your question there.  Full disclosure: I am not a user of that site, so I don't know if your question is a better fit there.  But there are quite a few posts on [Bayesian hierarchical models](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=bayesian+hierarchical).

Comment: Why do you think the views are unique? Why do you think that if 25 people saw the question, then all 25 agree it's a good question? Why do you think that if 25 people saw the question, and all agreed it is a good question, any of them would know the answer?

Answer (score 2):

Having a good question is no guarantee that your question will be answered, or even appreciated enough to receive upvotes. After reading your question myself, I certainly don't have the expertise to judge whether or not your question is good. This is a common thing that happens with "harder" math questions that are asked on this site: if your question is highly specialized, then there are fewer users of the site who will view it, and who are capable of appreciating it and answering it.

Related: [How do some seemingly easy questions get hundreds of upvotes?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27012/how-do-some-seemingly-easy-questions-get-hundreds-of-upvotes)

Comment: Asking a question from a rather special place (Bayesian statistics), using the local jargon, abbreviations, symbols, "a Zellner prior" without any explanation, you should not expect much understanding, let alone interest. Under these circumstances, 2 out of 25 is a remarkable performance.